# ReactJS - opening url in new tab not working properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url

I want to open url in new tab. I used `window.open("url", "_blank").focus()`. I have url for example "localhost:3000/index" and I open url "www.page.com" and it opens new tab with url "localhost:3000/www.page.com". But I want just "www.page.com". In my project I also use BrowserRouter from react-router-dom. Is it the reason why it is not working?

Thanks for any answer

Comment: You would want to open `http://www.page.com` not `www.page.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use https:// at the beginning of the url if you are directing to a page out of the application.

```
window.open("https://www.page.com","_blank");
```

[source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536651(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: It is not the best solution for me but thank you very much!